# Using an RSA public key on iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, rsa

I am working on an application where I will retrieve a public key for a user from our server.  Once I have it, I need to do a RSA encryption using the public key.  The public key obtained from the server is Base64 encoded.

How do I load the public key into the iOS KeyChain so that I can perform RSA cryptographic functions with it?  Certificate loading seems to be trivial, but raw public keys don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the necessary code on the Apple Site describing how to strip the ASN.1 header from the Public Key and load it into the KeyChain.

Comment: Can you provide a link to what you found?

Comment: Here's a link to an Apple Dev Forum discussion on the related topic of trying to load a private key: https://devforums.apple.com/message/684705  Loading public keys was simply a matter of switching the kSecAttrKeyClass to specify a public key.

Comment: [Chris Luke](http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/) writes about this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to work around the available certificate system.

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported because **it is the ["wrong"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH2UB2uD-tA) way**.

The "**right**" way is to use [**a certificate**](https://devforums.apple.com/message/135288#135288).

To [quote "Quinn The Eskimo!"](https://devforums.apple.com/message/114555#114555).

> This is surprisingly easy.  You don't need to add the certificate to the keychain to handle this case.  Rather, just load the certificate data (that is, the contents of a .cer file) in your application (you can either get this from your bundle or off the network) and then create a certificate ref using SecCertificateCreateWithData.  From there you can extract a public key ref using a SecTrust object (SecTrustCreateWithCertificates, SecTrustEvaluate -- you can choose to ignore the resulting SecTrustResultType -- and SecTrustCopyPublicKey).  And from there you can encrypt and verify using the SecKey APIs (SecKeyEncrypt, SecKeyRawVerify).

A tutorial on [**how to create a self-signed certificate is here**](http://panoptic.com/wiki/aolserver/How_to_generate_self-signed_SSL_certificates).

The basic steps are:

```
#Make the -----RSA PRIVATE KEY----- file in PEM format
openssl genrsa -out privKey.pem 2048

#Make the -----CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
openssl req -new -key privKey.pem -out certReq.pem

#Make the actual -----CERTIFICATE-----
openssl x509 -req -days 30 -in certReq.pem -signkey privKey.pem -out certificate.pem

#Make the DER certificate.crt file from the certificate.pem
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.cer
```

If you double click that **.cer** on a Mac machine, it will offer to import it into keychain.

Resources:

- [**How to generate self signed certificates**](http://panoptic.com/wiki/aolserver/How_to_generate_self-signed_SSL_certificates)
- [**Common SSL commands**](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)

Comment: Given that what I had at the time was a bare public key, the work around was the only option.  There was no certificate I could use to load it from.  We did eventually put the public key into a certificate for other purposes.

Comment: The API is enforcing how it thinks you should do security by the methods it exposes.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of transporting a public key -is- inside a certificate, signed by some CA to prove that it is authentic.

Or maybe you are talking about a ssh public key?
in that case you would need a special ssh capable app to use it, these keys are usually not stored in the iOS keychain.

Comment: Unfortunately, the server stores all the public keys in Bas64 encoded ASN.1 format.  Can't change the server as too many other existing clients rely on it.  And since we aren't using the keys for authentication, having them in certificates isn't necessary.

Comment: a certificate is usually encoded as a base64 encoded asn1 encoded x509 wrapped public key.  you should check if  `openssl x509 -in yourcert -text`  gives any readable output.  or otherwise maybe  `openssl x509 -in yourcert -inform DER -text`