# iOS: Adding a Private Key to the devices KeyChain

Tags: ios, cryptography, rsa, keychain, private-key

I have a project where I receive an encrypted RSA private key for a user from a server.  Using information provided by the user, I am able to decrypt the data back into an expected format.  However, I cannot figure out how to load the private key into the iOS Keychain for use in RSA crypto functions.

Currently, I have the following code that I have cobbled together from various examples.  This code works will for adding a public key, but doesn't seem to work at all for adding a private key.

```
[peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:peerTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:privateKeyData forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[peerPublicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];

sanityCheck = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) peerPublicKeyAttr) ;

sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) peerPublicKeyAttr, (CFTypeRef *)&privateKey);
```

When I run this code with the private key data (decoded into DER format), the `privateKey` variable is set to NULL by the `SecItemAdd()` call.  However, the `sanityCheck` variable indicates "No Error".  I'm at a loss for what I'm missing.

What do I need to do to get the private key to load into the keychain successfully?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an RSA public key on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728799/using-an-rsa-public-key-on-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Official response from Apple](https://devforums.apple.com/message/641836#641836) on this exact subject was that it was unsupported.  The only supported way of getting private keys into the Keychain was through PKCS#12 files.

Comment: But then how do you access that private key after you import it?

Comment: Once you have imported the P12 file, you can access the private key using the SecItemCopyMatching() function.

Comment: The link in this answer does not work. It redirects to https://developer.apple.com/account.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now... some links with more detailed information/sample source etc.:

- http://blog.wingsofhermes.org/?p=75 (pay attention to this [comment](http://blog.wingsofhermes.org/?p=75#comment-1601) too)
- https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-Certificate--Key--and-Trust-Sample-Project (this does exactly what you want)
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html
- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_11
- http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/